# joomla 1.5 : how to open a pdf file in popup window?

Tags: joomla

I have placed the following code in my newly created templates index.php in the head section.

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal');?>
```

And this is the link to which I want to show in popup.

```
<a class="modal" href="images/stories/loyalty-benefits.pdf" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 680, y: 370}}">
```

Anything is wrong there? Or is it because of my newly created template?

**Edit**

I tried to old templates too, but not showing popup window here too.

**Edit2**

I came to know when I place the link inside the article it is not showing popup but works in module. Anything to do?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Toretto Popup window is not appearing. it is opening directly.

Comment: Have you checked that `modal.js` is loaded on your site.Also check the console, if there is any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the following code in /templates/my-site/html/com_content/article/default.php and worked.

```
<?php
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How PDF's are rendered depends entirely on the browser you are using. Up until recently, only WebKit based browsers (and FireFox w/extensions) would even display PDF's in the browser. But even still, there aren't any (that I'm aware of) that will treat a PDF as an image and allow you to open it in a lightbox.

I've actually had to deal with this previously from a client request. They basically demanded to be able to view PDF's in the lightbox we had created for them, and weren't taking "but browsers don't work that way" for an answer. (facepalm) So, what I ended up doing was taking his 75 page PDF and splitting it up into 75 JPG images, and then loading them, full resolution, into the lightbox. It worked, I finally got paid, and then I fired the client.

TL;DR; If you have any control over the decision making process for this site you're doing, don't try to view PDF's in a lightbox. It's a battle you can't win until it's supported by browsers. Let the browser render the PDF natively.